# How To Solve CA2202:To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException Warning

Tags: c#, file, json.net, warnings

Every time on visual studio 2015, when i run `Code Analysis`, there are some annoying warnings. All of them are in a methods like this:

**here is my method:**

```
public static JObject ReadJson(string file_path)
{
    try {
        JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(file_path));
        using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(file_path))
        {
            using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
            {
                return (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);//the warning is here
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return default(JObject);
    }

}
```

so why this warning occur? How to solve it? And the most important is what
my fault in this method it seems to me very perfect

**Warning Description**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Warning        CA2202 :
>   Microsoft.Usage : Object 'file' can be disposed more than once in
>   method 'JsonHelper.ReadJson(string)'. To avoid generating a
>   System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than
>   one time on an object.

Comment: I'm Using 
`using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx)

> Nested using statements (Using in Visual Basic) can cause violations
>   of the CA2202 warning. If the IDisposable resource of the nested inner
>   using statement contains the resource of the outer using statement,
>   the Dispose method of the nested resource releases the contained
>   resource. When this situation occurs, the Dispose method of the outer
>   using statement attempts to dispose its resource for a second time.

**Problem:**

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(file_path))
{
    using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
    {
        return (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);//the warning is here
    }   //"file" will be disposed here for first time when "reader" releases it
}   //and here it will be disposed for the second time and will throw "ObjectDisposedException"
```

**Solution:**

You need to do it like this(disposing the object in *finally* block when all goes right, or in catch block when an error occurs):

```
public static JObject ReadJson(string file_path)
{   
    StreamReader file = null;
    try {
        JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(file_path));
        file = File.OpenText(file_path);
        using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
        {
            return (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return default(JObject);
    }
    //dispose "file" when exiting the method
    finally
    {
        if(file != null)
            file.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to remove the dispose from the catch, or you'll double-dispose here too...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Yup ! thanks for pointing.

Comment: This answer misses the key part of the linked documentation. Since the `JsonTextReader` object calls `Dispose()` on the underlying `StreamReader` that it is passed when itself is `Dispose()`-ed, you should not call it yourself. The solution is to reset your reference to the `StreamReader` to null inside the `using (JsonTextReader...)` block so you don't re-`Dispose()` in your `finally`. What you have posted basically the expansion the compiler does for you when using `using` (albeit slightly different since you share the existing `try` block), and does not fix the CA warning.